# TfLite LSTM models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have not found any pretrained lstm models to work with .
Did tfLite provided any pretrained lstm models ?
I tried to create tflite model but facing issues while conversion ? Could you provide exact script to create tfLite model ?
Does tfLite has any script for creating tfLite LSTM models with latest version ?
This is my script to create tfLite model. But its not working.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf



model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Add an Embedding layer expecting input vocab of size 1000, and
# output embedding dimension of size 64.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=64))

# Add a LSTM layer with 128 internal units.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128))

# Add a Dense layer with 10 units.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.summary()
#model.fit_generator(train_data_generator.generate(), len(train_data)//(batch_size*num_steps), num_epochs,
#                        validation_data=valid_data_generator.generate(),
#                        validation_steps=len(valid_data)//(batch_size*num_steps), callbacks=[checkpointer])
tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model_keras_dir")

model.save('my_lstm_model')
# x_train = 
#(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
#x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Cast x_train & x_test to float32.
#x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
#x_test = x_test.astype(np.float32)

#model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
#model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)



# Step 3: Convert the Keras model to TensorFlow Lite model.

tflite_model = converter.convert()
#sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
#input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('embedding_1:0')
#output_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dense_1:0')
#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(
    sess, [input_tensor], [output_tensor])

#tflite = converter.convert()
print('Model converted successfully!')


# Save the model.
with open('lstmmodel.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: Pretrained models for what? Speech recognition? Stock prediction? Language modeling?

Answer (score 2):

To expand Tian Lin's answer, here is the link to a Colab notebook showing LSTM conversion: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/experimental_new_converter/Keras_LSTM_fusion_Codelab.ipynb

As I know, there are no pre-trained LSTM models for TF Lite... But you can try to have a look at the **TF Lite Model Hub**: https://tfhub.dev/s?deployment-format=lite

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is one page describing RNN conversion: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/rnn. You may want to try it.