# Proper way of converting Keras LSTM model into TFLite for Android

Tags: android, keras, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I have created a simple LSTM model that I want to use in my Android application. I converted it into TFLite model and saved it in a .tflite file.
I imported the model into my project accoring to [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android) and everything seems okay - Android Studio shows me the sample codes I should use when I want to use it, except when I attempt to, I get this error when building:

> error: package com.example.app.ml does not exist
> import com.example.app.ml.SnoreModel

What I found out is that when I use a model that does not contain a LSTM layer, it works fine. I tried two different ways of converting my Keras model into TFLite, one was from saved model (as shown bellow) and the other was from loaded model. In both cases I had to set *supported_ops* and *_experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = false* otherwise the conversion would fail.

```
    TFLITE_SAVE_FILE = "SnoreModel.tflite"
    converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(filepath)
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS] 
    converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False

    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    with open(TFLITE_SAVE_FILE, 'wb') as tflite_model_file:
        tflite_model_file.write(tflite_model)
```

The keras model was saved like so:

```
    model.save(KERAS_SAVE_FILE)
```

I am using the latest version of Android Studio and am compiling for min Android API 27. In build.gradle for the application I use the following for tflite, the error was the same whether I used *org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.7.0* or not, the rest was automatically added by Android Studio when I imported the model:

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-audio:0.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.0'
```

What I would like to ask is: Is there something wrong with the way I convert my model? And if yes, how would I fix it, since most of the issues I found were fairly old and were linked to Android Studio version. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen: [TfLite LSTM models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64609796/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang No I have not, will read through it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang So I have read through the replies and the links they provided, but I can't say it has helped. I adjusted my model a little bit to contain even 'Input' layer, instead of just providing input_shape to the LSTM layer, but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't show any details on reason for failure or if it is even related to TFLite.

One thing missing is if you are converting your model with SELECT_TF_OPS and the model has some Select TF ops, then you will need to add dependency like

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

See more information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#android_aar) to be able to cut the binary size.

Comment: I know the error itself doesn't point to TFLite, but everything I tried points to it, at least some partial incompatibility between Android and TFLite LSTM.
Edit: I am going to try to add this and see if this helps

Comment: I tried importing the LSTM model with this dependency, but still no change, the same error.

Comment: As i said the message doesn't look related to TFLite. Try capturing the logcat and see if there is another related message.

Comment: well the thing is, this issue happens during build and there is nothing else written besides the error.

Right now I am using another model that is imported the exact same way, except it does not use LSTM layer and it works just fine. The same import path, the same way of converting from keras to tflite (minus the TF_OPS - I might try converting it with these to see if it would work).

Comment: So I tested out converting the non-LSTM model with OPS, and it is still working fine.

Comment: I would go with one of the TFLite example [apps](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples), and try loading the different models there. To make sure everything is set correctly.

Comment: I am sorry for the long silence. I looked through the site, checked the audio classification stuff and all I saw was how to use their pre-trained models in Android / iOS, or how to further train their model.

Edit: Hit enter way too soon - For now I just stopped using LSTM layers